# googleスプレッドシート、QUERY関数の正しい書き方についての質問

Tags: google-spreadsheet

スプレッドシートのquery関数を使い、指定した商品の販売個数を月ごとに表示したいです。

そこで、書き方を調べて次の数式を書いてみました。

```
=query('シート1'!C:L,"select C WHERE C contains '革' group by MONTH(G)",1)
```

ですが、下記のエラーメッセージが出てしまい関数が動かないです。

```
関数queryのパラメータ2のクエリ文字列を解析できません:CANNOT_GROUP_WITHOUT_AGG
```

式の書き方に間違いがあるのかなと思うのですが、どの部分を直せば良いか、ぜひご教示いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `=query('シート1'!C:L,"select C WHERE C contains '革' group by MONTH(G)",1)`はどこに書いたのでしょうか？セルですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。先ほど解決致しましたのでご報告いたします。=query('シート1'!C:L,"select year(G),month(G)+1,count(C) WHERE C contains '革' group by year(G),month(G)+1 label year(G) '年',month(G)+1 '月',count(C) '革・販売個数'",TRUE)　という内容のコードで表が作れました。わざわざご協力くださり、ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決してよかったです、後から同じ問題にぶつかる人のために、自己回答することが推奨されています。よろしくお願いします。